# Drag multiple polygons at once in Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It is extremely easy to make a polygon draggable in the Google Maps API v3 with the 'draggable' option.

How could I go about dragging multiple polygons at once, however?

The idea is that the user selects some polygons somehow (not the issue here: could be by clicking, drawing a bigger polygon, etc.), and then is able to drag any one of them and see them all move together to the destination.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to create a single polygon instead of multiple polygons.  Polygons may have multiple paths, so you could merge all polygons into 1.